# application causing orange flashing in taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

Sometimes when our application launches it flashes orange in the taskbar.  I don't think we explicitly wrote any code to do this but it still happens.  Our program is a c# winforms app that sometimes takes a while to load.  Any ideas what could be causing this and how I can prevent it?

Comment: Is this on a specific version of Windows (i.e. 7)?

Comment: The system is doing this on your behalf. I'm not sure there's much you can do about it.

Comment: Can "sometimes" be defined exactly? When you activate another window until it is loading or what?

Comment: I wish "sometimes" could be defined exactly.  It will happen repeatedly for a while and then not happen for a long time.  It may be related to what programs/windows are currently open or window positioning, but if there is a pattern, I haven't been able to figure it out.  Windows 7.  It's not minimized, but it doesn't have the focus, either (which we want).

Comment: It is very intermittent on my desktop.  There is a Windows 7 laptop that seems to get the problem every single time (I'm wondering if it is timing/performance related)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use MSDN's **[flashwinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679347%28VS.85%29.aspx)** .

Edit - Here's some more [info](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2008/04/19/3392.aspx) .

Comment: He doesn't want to make it happen, he wants to make it stop happening.

Comment: you may want to delete your comment before you lose more points.

Comment: Please try actually reading the links I included.  The second link describes using FLASHW_STOP to get the flashing to stop.  Thanks for the blind downvotes btw.

Comment: My -1 was based on the understanding that `SPI_SETFOREGROUNDFLASHCOUNT` controls how Windows does the flashing on its end. `FLASHWINFO` controls when you do flashing on your end. I assume using `FLASHWINFO` the user would have to continuously call it with FLASHW_STOP?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, if the application isn't the current application the user is using, but does something 'on its own' to update the UI(?) the system recognizes this and notifies the user by the orange flash thing.

So if your application is doing some long processing and the user clicks away to another application/window, they probably will get the orange flash.

Comment: I get the problem even if all I do is double-click the icon to launch the program and keep very still :)

Comment: I think we will end up advising to set registry key HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimout = 0.  It is not ideal, but it seems to be the only thing to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative would be to prevent the application from showing in the Taskbar until loading has completed.

So, something along the lines of:

```
// prevent from showing in the constructor (or via the designer)
public MyAppMainForm()
{
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    // other initialization
}

// now you're ready to show in the Taskbar
private void MyAppMainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
}
```